# Why would a react native animation be completed before the duration had expired?

Tags: react-native

I have a fade animation in my componentDidUpdate function :

```
   if (prevState.fadeStarting !== this.state.fadeStarting){
         const fadestart = new Animated.Value(1);
         this.setState(
            {fadeStarting: false,animFade:fadestart},
            () => {
               Animated.timing(
                  this.state.animFade, {
                     toValue: 0.0,
                     duration: 100000000,
                  }
               ).start(this.endFade())
            }
         )
      }
```

I assumed that the endFade method would only be called after the duration expired, but the endFade method is called instantly. Is there any reason that this animation would end early?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you mean `start(this.endFade)` instead?

You mean to pass the callback function, not its result (which is evaluated immediately).

Comment: Thank you so much!